# CSS Working With 100%

Tags: css, height, percentage

Consider [this jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZVZGh/).

I need the `content` to always stretch to meet the bottom of it's parent container (which could be any height). Essentially I want it to look like this:

[image]

Comment: Is that not what it's doing?

Comment: You cant do this without setting a 'static' height somewhere, unless you use javascript.

Comment: @Rice_Crisp I'm viewing the example in chrome and it looks exactly like the image I've attached.

Comment: @veelen I was afraid of that. I know how to do this in javascript but I'm trying to find out a css trick to accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help?: http://jsfiddle.net/Boroso/8rXnL/ Edit: Sorry, original link was wrong.

Changing the height of the container to *auto* will allow for
the change of height in content. Which is what I assume you
are asking.

```
#box {
    width:300px;
    height:auto;    
    border:1px solid;
}

div.content {
    width: auto;
    height: 300px;
    background:#333;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

Also, you shouldn't add padding to the container because that will change
the height and width of it that you'd probably like to have. Because of that I set the div.content to use a margin of 10px on all sides.

Comment: ooh, upvote for technically answering the question perfect, but unfortunately `height:auto` causes my real project's `overflow:scroll` to not work.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, just set a `max-height` and `overflow: scroll`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible in pure CSS, if the box height and the content before it varies in height. I've put together a small Javascript which automatically adjusts the `#content` height depending on the height of `#box` and the paragraph above's height and margins.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var p = $('#box > p:first-child');
  var margin_top = p.css('margin-top').substring(0,p.css('margin-top').length-2);
  var margin_bot = p.css('margin-bottom').substring(0,p.css('margin-bottom').length-2);
  var box_height = $('#box').css('height').substring(0, $('#box').css('height').length-2);
  var p_height = p.css('height').substring(0,p.css('height').length-2);
  var content_height = box_height - p_height - margin_top - margin_bot;
  $('#content').css('height', content_height+'px');
});
```

JSFiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/ueeMW/

Answer (score 0):

Why not just using less height?

Like this:

```
height: 85%;
```